# Assertion failure trying to add a new phone number to an existing address book contact

Tags: ios

I've got the following code to add an additional phone number to an existing contact that already has some phone numbers. However its failing at the ABMultiValueAddValueAndLabel call with what looks like an internal address book assertion:

> Assertion failed: (((ABCMultiValue *)multiValue)->flags.isMutable),
>   function ABMultiValueAddValueAndLabel, file
>   /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/AddressBook/AddressBook-11112.5/ABMultiValue.c,
>   line 110.

```
CFErrorRef error = nil;
    ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(NULL, &error);
CFArrayRef people = ABAddressBookCopyPeopleWithName(addressBook, CFSTR("SOME NAME"));
    ABRecordRef person;
    if ((people != nil) && (CFArrayGetCount(people) > 0))
    {
        // add new phone numbers to existing contact
        person = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(people, 0);
        ABMutableMultiValueRef phoneNumbers  = (__bridge ABMutableMultiValueRef)((__bridge NSMutableDictionary *)ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonPhoneProperty));
        ABMultiValueAddValueAndLabel(phoneNumbers, (__bridge CFStringRef)@"2063333333", kABPersonPhoneMainLabel, NULL);
        ABRecordSetValue(person, kABPersonPhoneProperty, phoneNumbers, nil);
        ABAddressBookAddRecord(addressBook, person, nil);
```

However, fairly similar code to create a new entry is ok when ABMultiValueAddValueAndLabel is called:

```
person = ABPersonCreate();
ABRecordSetValue(person, kABPersonFirstNameProperty, @"SOME NAME", nil);
ABMutableMultiValueRef phoneNumbers  = ABMultiValueCreateMutable(kABMultiStringPropertyType);
ABMultiValueAddValueAndLabel(phoneNumbers, (__bridge CFStringRef)@"2061111111", kABPersonPhoneMainLabel, NULL);
ABMultiValueAddValueAndLabel(phoneNumbers, (__bridge CFStringRef)@"2062222222", kABPersonPhoneMainLabel, NULL);
ABRecordSetValue(person, kABPersonPhoneProperty, phoneNumbers, nil);
ABAddressBookAddRecord(addressBook, person, nil);
```

Why does ABMultiValueAddValueAndLabel succeed in the second code snippet but fail in the first?

Comment: `ABRecordCopyValue` returns an immutable value, use `ABMultiValueCreateMutableCopy` to create a mutable copy if you want to change it

Comment: Thanks, that did the job